# Extract coordinates and labels from dwg/dxf file using python

Tags: python, dxf, dwg

I need to extract coordinates of the room and label associated with it from the dwg file.As i have floor plans of office buildings, rooms are generally of square / rectangle shape.
I have multiple floor plans in dwg format.

It will be really helpful if anyone can show me a way to do so or even guidance to look for.
I was trying with dxfgrabber library to extract data from dxf file(after converting dwg files to dxf). But i was not able/clear to extract coordinates and labels.

Comment: There exists no DXF entity like ROOM, so you have to examine the geometry entities, if you are lucky you have block references for each room with room parameters as attributes. At least you have to provide some example drawings, if you want help from somebody else.

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of examples in my post. I've attached an sample image. Floor Plan [https://imgur.com/a/NoeUXL6]

Yes i'm trying to analyse the file so what i can write a script to extract information.